# The usage of "grow many times" in "Apple's stock price has the potential to grow many times in future"

Tags: phrase-usage

What I want to express is that apple's stock price in my opinion can grow up 10 times or 15 times or X times more, but I don't want to put a specific number here since the range of number can be large, so I think saying "many times" might be OK. However, I googled this expression but saw it appearing nowhere. So I want to ask for help if the expression "grow many times" fits here or other expressions are better.

Comment: I think "grow many times" could be ambiguous - does it mean on many occasions or by a large amount? "She grew tomatoes many times" wouldn't mean they increased in size X times. I'm not sure what's a better way of expressing this.

Comment: A price _increases_.

Comment: What @StuartF said. But obviously in practice it's not likely anyone would assume the "price increase on many separate occasions" meaning. We can say the price may ***increase by a factor of N*** where N is an integer (or perhaps a specific range, such as ***a factor of 4 to 6***), but I don't see any way to include a less specific term such as ***many*** or ***several*** in that construction. Switch to percentages, then something like ***increase by several hundred percent*** would convey the intended sense more "elegantly".

Comment: The main reason I parse *grow many times* as *increase **by a factor of** [many]* is because the ***on many separate occasions*** version doesn't make much sense. But it occurs to me that simply including the additional preposition *grow many times **over*** would make me choose the correct interpretation on ***syntactic*** as well as ***semantic*** grounds. Maybe that's just me, though.

Answer (score 1):

"grow many times" can be ambiguous, I recommend you not use it. It's better to use simpler terms and go straight to the point:

> Apple's stock price has the potential to increase in the future

Note you are missing a "the" before "future".